# Visual Studio setup proxy authentication fails

Tags: proxy, visual-studio-2015, ntlm

I am installing Visual Studio 2015 behind corp firewall. The setup fails to install some components with the message *HTTP status 407: proxy authentication is required*. This must be a common problem, but I have dug around and haven't found a suitable solution yet.

Is there a way to configure proxy authentication for Visual Studio setup? [This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn771556.aspx) explains for devenv; would configuring for the setup work similarly?